# How do I make a 25 bit wide unsigned integer alongside a boolean bit?

Tags: c, performance, memory, struct

I was hoping to use bit fields, there's no reason why such a thing would take 5 bytes when I can compress both into 4 bytes, after all, I have 7 bits I don't need in my 25 bit integer, however, avr-gcc is giving me an error upon compliation-

```
error: width of ‘prettybignum’ exceeds its type
     unsigned int prettybignum : 25;
```

Also, I have another error -

```
useless storage class specifier in empty declaration [-Werror]
 };
```

My struct looks something like this:

```
typedef struct tinyBitmap // Should take 4 bytes per instance
{
    unsigned int prettybignum : 25;
    bool yesorno : 1;
};
```

Am I doing something wrong in my struct definition?

Edit: sorry for writing that it should be 3 bytes. I meant to say 4 bytes. I know how that works, my wrong. Either way, yes, I'm trying to compress everything into as few bytes as possible and I just discovered bit fields yesterday, and I'm really happy to have discovered them. I was trying to do that sort of thing manually without abstraction (using bit shifting to store 8 booleans in one uint) and I was hoping C had a away to abstract all this madness away and make it easy to manage and access in my program (without needing special helper functions)

Comment: How can you compress 26 bits into 24 bits? The error also suggests unsigned int is 16 bits on that platform and cannot hold 25 bits.

Comment: Yep, I just miscalculated. I meant to say 4 bytes because 5 would be wasteful.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> error: width of ‘prettybignum’ exceeds its type
>      unsigned int prettybignum : 25;
> ```

C allows implementations some latitude with respect to the sizes of their integer types.  Type `unsigned int` can be as narrow as 16 bits.  Use type `long int` instead if you must have at least 25 value bits, or if you want to ensure that you are as parsimonious as possible then include `stdint.h` and use type `uint_least32_t`.

> ```
> useless storage class specifier in empty declaration [-Werror]
>  };
> ```

The compiler is pointing out that you are using the form of a type alias declaration but not specifying any identifier to serve as an alias.  Such an identifier (or identifiers) would normally go between the closing brace of the `struct` declaration within and the overall declaration's terminating semicolon, which is why the compiler is showing these to you.  This would normally be a warning, not an error, but you have also requested that the compiler treat all warnings as errors.

You can clear it up by either

- removing the useless (in the declaration as presently written) `typedef` keyword.  This is not necessary for declaring a structure types; rather, it is for defining type aliases.
- specifying an identifier to serve as the alias for type `struct tinyBitmap`.

> My struct looks something like this:
>
> ```
> typedef struct tinyBitmap // Should take 3 bytes per instance
> {
>     unsigned int prettybignum : 25;
>     bool yesorno : 1;
> };
> ```

In addition, considering your declaration ...

> ```
> typedef struct tinyBitmap // Should take 3 bytes per instance
> ```

... shows that you seem to have a misconception.  Three bytes provide only 24 bits, so if your structure contains a 25-bit bitfield then it must occupy at least 32 bits (for `CHAR_BIT == 8`, which is almost certainly your case).

Overall, then, you have multiple options, but supposing that the objective is minimum storage, these are your two best:

- Without a `typedef`, so that the type will be referenced as `struct tinyBitmap`

  ```
  #include <stdint.h>

  struct tinyBitmap {
      uint_least32_t prettybignum : 25;
      bool yesorno : 1;
  };
  ```
- With a `typedef`, so that the type can be referenced not only as `struct tinyBitmap`, but also as some other identifier(s) you choose, such as "my_bitmap":

  ```
  #include <stdint.h>

  typedef struct tinyBitmap {
      uint_least32_t prettybignum : 25;
      bool yesorno : 1;
  } my_bitmap;
  ```

And to drive home the point that `typedef` is not part of a structure definition, I observe that the latter can be written equivalently and more clearly as two separate statements:

```
#include <stdint.h>

struct tinyBitmap {
    uint_least32_t prettybignum : 25;
    bool yesorno : 1;
};

typedef struct tinyBitmap my_bitmap;
```

Comment: And if I understand correctly, I don't HAVE to name the struct, if I use typedef and give it an alias after the struct's definition, right?

Comment: Yes, @Liran, that is another alternative, whether you use `typedef` or not.  In fact, it provides perhaps the clearest explanation for the meaning and use of `typedef`.  Suppose you provide one or more identifiers between the closing brace of the `struct` declaration and the subsequent semicolon.  Without `typedef`, those identifiers designate *objects* whose type is that structure type.  With `typedef`, the identifiers instead designate *aliases* for the type itself.